# how to connect to my university unix server using mac terminal

Tags: macos, unix, ssh

I have a unix  class in school and we need to log into the server which is an address like:

something.something.ac.il

in this connection the other students had to download putty , and they use telnet too...

From what I know I can use mac terminal to connect to the school server with ssh, i'v seen some posts say to do something like: `ssh username@something.something.ac.il` but this docent work for me...I get an error:

```
ssh: connect to host something.something.ac.il port 22: Operation timed out
```

I know my port is 23, and we use telnet..

Please help me to log in through terminal...tnx!

I use an app called DOC that works fine that its configurations looks like this:

[image]

but i want to use terminal

Comment: Port 23 is `telnet`, not `ssh`.  The command, like the protocol, and the human name, is different. But it's insecure, and you should ask your university about a secure alternative.

Comment: but how can I connect to the server with the terminal...even if it's not secure this moment

Comment: The command is `telnet something.something.ac.il`

Comment: write is as an answer, it's working for me :)

Comment: It's off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your figure - you are connecting to a telnet server as tripleee suggested.  From your mac terminal you should be able to connect using:

```
telnet something.something.ac.il 23
```

and you should get prompted for a username and password.  Or you could do:

```
telnet -l username something.something.ac.il 23
```

In the odd chance that your university is using ssh from a different port (it's not that uncommon, but it would be uncommon to use a port designated to another service).  You can specify the port number with ssh on the command-line:

```
ssh user@something.something.ac.il -p 23
```